# How to know if another thread is accessing a ressource?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm having one thread writing a file to document directory while another thread will try to access that file and check if it's available in order to use it otherwise it will use a temporary variable instead. My question is how can I test if the other thread has finished writing the file or if it is writing as I am checking the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking for a completion, you could force the write to be atomic by using an auxiliary file.

If you are writing your document using an API that supports auxiliary files, similar to `[NSString writeToFile:... atomically:YES encoding:... error:...]`, the change is as easy as flipping a switch.

If you are writing the file yourself, write to a file with a different name first, close the file, and then rename it to the desired name.

For example, in the call that writes the document to `@"myfile.doc"`, you could write the document to `@"myfile.doc_aux"`, and then rename it to `@"myfile.doc"`. If the second thread checks for the presence of `@"myfile.doc"` before writing is finished, the check would fail. When the check succeeds, though, you can be certain that the file has been written to completion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to check if it's being used by the other thread, because the other thread could start using it immediately after your check.

Instead, what you want is a lock, or a synchronization point. Take a look at `@synchronized()` and NSLock, both of which can help you ensure data integrity while multi threading.